# Django: Extend jQuery CDN from base

Tags: django, cdn

I thought that by just including jQuery from CDN in `base.html`, it will be defined in all html pages that extend the base, like when including from static files, without repeating

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**base.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>notifyMe</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->

<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>NotifyMe</h1>
{% block main %}
{% endblock %}

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**
**event_add.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
    <div id="form" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 jumbotron">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3>New Task</h3>
        </div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {{field|add_class:'form-control'}}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <span class="help-block"> {{ error}} </span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save
                </button>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true,
                      yearRange: "2016:2020",
                                        });
                    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

My function wasn't recognize until I added the CDN line before the function script.

Does `{% extends 'base.html' %}` have some limits?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What problems do you have?

Comment: I've been struggling with `Uncaught TypeError: $(…).datepicker is not a function ..` for a while now and the last thing i tried worked which is including jQuery again. Just want to understand what's the difference and if there's a trick to not repeat myself when working with CDN.

Comment: Where in the `base.html` file are you including the `script` tag? Add the relevant parts of your file to your question and describe the problem you have - I _assume_ you are not able to run jQuery on extended pages? You should check the console of your browser for any error messages.

Comment: The order matters. You should first include Jquery, then datepicker, then your custom script that uses datepicker. I assume that in the `base.html` JQuery is included at the end of page while you are trying to use it somewhere above that.

Comment: @Selcuk I put it at the top it didn't work, now when adding this too `<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js'></script>` it worked. Why?

Comment: JQuery and JQuery-UI are not the same thing. Your `base.html` does not have any `{% block %}` tags in it, how do you extend that? Please post the actual contents of your templates, not hyptothetical ones.

Comment: @Selcuk I edited my post, it didn't work until i included both at the top, I am new to JQuery, does my function need JQuery-UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.datepicker()` plugin you try to use is included in Jquery-UI. I suggest you to restructure your templates as follows (irrelevant parts removed for clarity):

**base.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    ...
    ...
    {% block main %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Consider also adding Bootstrap.js here! -->
    {% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and use `main` block for HTML content and `extra_js` block for Javascript. This way you will guarantee that any user scripts will come after JQuery. For example:

**event_add.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
...
...
</div>
{% endblock main %}

{% block extra_js %}
<script src='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js'></scrip‌​t>
<script>
$(function() {
   ...
   ...
</script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```